# Are dynamic recordsets officially supported by Oracle?

Tags: c++, mysql, mfc, odbc

I want to update some records via ODBC interface (I use MFC).
I have installed MySQL ODBC driver 5.3 (Community edition), but it seems that neither 'dynasets' nor 'dynamic' recordsets are implemented.

Is it true? Is there any way to solve this problem?

I haven't found anything googling, but there`re a lot of posts with no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, 'dynasets' are not supported in MySQL: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37557